# Old midi file: possible video game soundtrack

Tags: identify-this-song, videogame-soundtrack

I was going through some of my old files (from 15-20 years ago), and came upon a lot of old midi files. Among them was [this one](https://onlinesequencer.net/584996). So far, I've had no luck in identifying the name of the song, or its author.

The song was in a folder containing mostly video game soundtracks, so it might have been used in / created for a video game.

Search on the popular online song identifiers (Midomi and the like) came back empty.

Comment: This is a well-known Celtic folk song, but I'm not sure which one.  Compare [The Swallowtail Jig](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZxAVUsuE4Y) for a similar song.

Comment: Thank you, you seem to have been right. I've started from the song you posted, and kept going through various suggested videos, but have had no luck,until Puzzlepumpkin posted his answer. Will vote your comment up, as soon as I'm able to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Chieftains album, Boil The Breakfast Early, there is a medley called Chase Around The Windmill. The second tune in this medley is entitled Ballinasloe Fair. This is the tune of your sample.
There seems to be several tunes with this title, but the Chieftain's version is definitely your tune.